# How to print the amount of files in a folder (recursively) seperated by extensions?

Tags: bash

For example, I have a folder containing files of different types (.jpg, .png, .txt, ..) and would like to know how many files of each extensions there is in my folder separatly.

The output would be something like this:

```
.jpg : 255
.png : 123
.txt : 12
No extension : 1
```

For now, I only know how to find how many files exist for one given extension using this command:

```
find /folderpath -type f -name '*.jpg' | wc -l
```

However I would like it to be able to find by itself the files extensions.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Should this descend in sub directories as your current command does?

Comment: Yes if it is possible.

Comment: I've produced an answer which handles the `No extensions` case if you have troubles handling it ; I'm not sure my use of archaic `sed` commands is a good idea though, so if you can adapt one of the other answers it would probably be best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this for a single directory with:

```
 ls | grep '\.' | sed 's/.*\././' | sort | uniq -c
```

(I'm ignoring files with no `.` - tweak if you want something else)

I'd suggest fleshing this out into a script (say, `extension_counts`) that takes a list of directories, and for each one outputs the path followed by the report in the format you wish.

Quick and dirty version:

```
 #!/bin/sh
 for dir in $*; do
     echo $dir
     (cd $dir && ls | grep '\.' | sed 's/.*\././' | sort | uniq -c)
 done
```

... but you should consider hardening this.

Then for the recursive part, you can use `find` and `xargs`:

```
 find . -type d | xargs extension_counts
```

You could be a bit smarter and do it all in one script file by defining `extension_counts` as a function, but that's an optimisation.

---

There are some pitfalls to parsing the output of `ls` (or `find`). In this case the only potential issue I can think of is filenames containing a newline (yes, this is possible). You could just accept that you're using a tool not designed for weird filenames, or you could write something more robust in a language with firmer data structures, such as Python, Perl, Ruby, Go, etc.

Comment: I wouldn't be able to point out how this could fail, but I've heard terrible things about working on the output of `ls`...

Comment: I'm amazed at how bash commands can be complex and short at the same time if you use them well! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Aaron well https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls -- but it's more of a problem when you're dealing with `ls -l`, and this doesn't. It's about all you can do in `bash`. It's true you could write something more robust in Python or Perl or whatever.

Comment: Why not use `find . -type f` instead of `ls` as `find . -type f | sed 's/.*\././' | sort | uniq -c`?

Comment: @slim I'm in the process of writing a solution using only `find` ; I'm not sure it'll be better than this one though.

Comment: @archimiro I don't want to descend subdirs before the `sed`.

Answer (score 2):

This could be done with a quick `awk` one liner as well:

```
find /folderpath -type f -name '*.*' | awk -F"." 'BEGIN{OFS=" : "}{extensions[$NF]++}END{for (ext in extensions) { print ext, extensions[ext]}};'
```

1. That awk script will split each line by a period `-F"."`
2. Set the OFS (Output Field Separator) by " : " `BEGIN{OFS=" : "}`
3. Load an array using the file extension for the key `extensions[$NF]` where $NF is the last field in the record. The value of the array will be a count `++`.
4. When all the lines are processed we iterate the array `for (ext in extensions)` and print out the index and value `{print ext, extensions[ext]}`

Answer (score 2):

I would proceed this way :

1. list the file names (rather than their paths produced by `find`) :

   `find . -type f | rev | cut -d/ -f1 | rev`

   We reverse each line so that we can easily address the last field
2. reduce to their extension :

   `sed -E 's/^.*\././;t end;s/.*/No extension/;:end'`

   Here we remove everything up to the first dot, or if the substitution could not be done (because there was no dot) we replace everything by "No extension".
3. sort the result :

   `sort`
4. group by extension and add the count :

   `uniq -c`

For a complete command as follows :

```
find . -type f | rev | cut -d/ -f1 | rev | sed -E 's/^.*\././;t end;s/.*/No extension/;:end' | sort | uniq -c
```

Note that the presentation differs from yours, which could be easily fixed with an additional `sed` :

```
      2 .119
      1 .147
      [...]
      1 .Xauthority
      1 .xml
      1 .xsession-errors
      2 .zip
      1 .zshrc
     48 No extension
```

Comment: Aha, this differs from mine in that it summarises the whole tree, whereas mine gives a report per directory. Not sure which one OP wanted.

Comment: @slim oh, true, I didn't saw that you did a summary by directory.

Comment: This gives me an error and I can't find a way to fix it. Here's the error: `sed: 1: "s/^.*\././;t end;s/.*/N ...": undefined label 'end;s/.*/No extension/;:end'`

Comment: @cycreek that's weird, looks like label names in your version don't stop at `;`. Maybe try to add a space after `end`? I'm not sure I'll be able to debug it, I don't know well different `sed` versions

Comment: @cycreek anyway JNevill give the same result as me (a global summary for the directory and its subdirs) with more modern `awk` aside from the "No extension" part which can be easily plugged in : remove the `-name` filter on `find`, then in `awk` check if `$NF` is empty, if so increment `extensions[No extension]`, else increment `extensions[$NF]` or something (I'm no good at `awk`, but this should work even if not optimal)